# Layouts within layouts in XML, what's a cleaner way of doing this?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

A "schematic" and an image of the desired layout is at the bottom where the outer frame represents the activity layout and the bottom frame is a container for the views (textview and imageview) inside of it.

This is what I tried:

Outer frame must be a relative layout so that its child, the container, can be placed on the bottom using the `android:layout_alignParentBottom` atribute.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
```

The container layout must be a linear layout with horizontal orientation.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
```

The two-view combo is placed in a layout of its own so that one can be above the other. I chose a linear layout for this. Each of these layouts have a weight so that maximum space can be used and shared appropriately.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

The views themselves are code repeated 3 times. I suppose I could use a seperate layout and use `<include>` but I'd need to be able to change them as they're not identical

> > Relative Layout
> >
> > > Linear Layout
> > >
> > > > Linear Layout
> > > >
> > > > > Views
> > > >
> > > > Linear Layout
> > > >
> > > > > Views
> > > >
> > > > Linear Layout
> > > >
> > > > > Views

[image: Layout]

Comment: what is your question ? so ambigious

Comment: @AlexHong Is the method I have shown the best way of achieving this design?

Comment: @Lobtsw It is acceptable. do not try to reduce view as much as possible. sometimes, it'll be hard to manage and maintain in the future. Otherwise, you can reduce nested linearlayout by using custom view for items at the bottom.